# New to Drupal 7 and I was wondering if this is possible to do?

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal 7 (it's been years since I touched Drupal 6) and I have a question regarding a concept.

Is it possible to "port" an external web applications into Drupal so it appears to be part of the website, but the app itself actually lives on another server? The external web application will have no dependencies on Drupal other than it's served up via Drupal so it appears to be part of the site.

Example - I build a webform an it lives on Server A, can I server it up via Drupal and keep all of the apps functionality?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can port an external web application, and can make it automatically compatible with your div specific properties. I suggest you to use jQuery to get external web application.

To add jquery in drupal 7, you need to install [JS injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module. Enable the module and you can add jquery at `admin -> config -> development -> js-injector`. In the JS code section, the syntax is as follows:

```
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.YOURTHEMENAME = {
attach: function(context, settings) {

   =====your jQuery code goes here ==========

}
};
})(jQuery);
```

For porting an external web application, let us assume you have a link/button in a specific div section and when you click on that link/button, I'm going to display that website in a target div section.

HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="sourceDiv">
   <a href="http://example.com"> Click here to port an external website. </a>
</div> 

<div id="targetDiv" style="width:720px; height:500px;"> 

</div>
```

And the jquery to port web application:

```
$('#sourceDiv a').on('click',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                                     //returns the targetDiv's height and width
    var height = $('#targetDiv').height();   
    var width = $('#targetDiv').width();
                                    //replaces the div with porting the website. 
    $('#targetDiv').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
    return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's certainly possible. One easy route is to embed the app as an iframe. Something like this Google Form:

`<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/embeddedform?formkey=MyFormKey" frameborder="0" width="500" height="300" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>`

Assuming your source web application URL doesn't display a design around around the interface, it should embed fine into a Drupal content page.

If your source web application URL does have a design around the interface, you'll have to do something more complicated where Drupal will act like a proxy around the source web application.